# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'imshow'

Tags: python, numpy

I've been trying everything I can to get pyplot to display an image 5 times. I keep getting this error...

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os.path
import numpy as np

'''Read the image data'''
# Get the directory of this python script
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# Build an absolute filename from directory + filename
filename = os.path.join(directory, 'cat.gif')
# Read the image data into an array
img = plt.imread(filename)

'''Show the image data'''
# Create figure with 1 subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 5)
# Show the image data in a subplot

for i in ax:
    ax.imshow(img, interpolation='none')
# Show the figure on the screen
fig.show()
```

I'm sure it has something to do with the 2D array, but I really cant figure it out.

Ive tried

```
for i in ax:
    ax[i].imshow(img, interpolation='none')
# Show the figure on the screen
fig.show()
```

But I just get:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
>   numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: `i` isn't an index. It's an element in your array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This:

```
for i in ax:
    ax[i].imshow(img, interpolation='none')
```

doesn't make sense because `I` isn't the index. It's one of the axis objects.

And your first case is wrong because even though you loop over the items, you call the function on `ax`, not the individual axes.

Do this:

```
for a in ax:
    a.imshow(img, interpolation='none')
```

Answer (score 8):

just add this command before "**ax.flatten()**" ​before your code

```
ax = ax.flatten()
for a in ax:
    a.imshow(img, interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

*Just a little addition to the previous answers:*

When containing multiple axes, the variable `axs` will be a **2D ndarray**. For example, the subplots as 3 rows and 2 columns can be created using:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=3, figsize=(8, 10))

>> axs
array([[<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>],
       [<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>],
       [<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>]], dtype=object)
```

This 2D ndarray requires two indices, and **to make it work within a loop, a single index is needed**. Therefore it must be **flattened first** to have a 1D ndarray of size (6,).

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=3, figsize=(8, 10))
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.ravel()):
    ax.imshow(img[i])
```

Alternatively, one may also do this if you want to keep it 2D

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=3, figsize=(8, 10))
ax = axs.ravel()
for i in range(5):
    ax[i].imshow(img[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check ax like below

```
type(ax)
>>> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

ax
>>> [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000028F13AFC668>
 <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000028F15C6FCF8>
 <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000028F15CA23C8>
 <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000028F15CC9A58>
 <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000028F15CFA160>]
```

if you really want to use 'i' then use **enumerate()** like this

```
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.imshow(img[i:i*100], interpolation='none')
```

'axs' is preferred because it is multiple.

finally, you can test below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data

'''Read the image data'''
img = data.chelsea()   # cat image

'''Show the image data'''
# Create figure with 1 subplot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=5, figsize=(10, 3))

print(axs)
# [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001D7A841C710>
#  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001D7AA58FCC0>
#  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001D7AA5C2390>
#  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001D7AA5E9A20>
#  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001D7AA61A128>]

print(axs.shape)  # (5,)

# Show the image data in a subplot
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    print(ax)     # AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.133621x0.77)
    img_made_changeable = img[i:(i + 2) * 50]
    ax.imshow(img_made_changeable, interpolation='none')

# Show the figure on the screen
plt.show()
```