# numpy.ndarray object has no attribute imshow

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to use python with jupyter notebook to come up with a scheme where you can hold on to a smart lightbulb and get information from the hand by diffuse reflectance. I've managed to make all of that work, and all of this is saved in a variable PIX:

```
PIX = np.array(pictures)
print(PIX.shape)
```

And this outputs an (81,480,640,3) just as expected (the 81 represents the visible spectrum converted to RGB so that the lamp gets it).

However, I now want to visualize the data, and I thought that imshow was the perfect implementation. I looked around and Datacamp had a nice summary of this in action and  copied and pasted from https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/biomedical-image-analysis-in-python/exploration?ex=11. I changed some of the variables so that the script looks like the following:

```
# Plot the images on a subplots array 
fig, axes = 
plt.subplots(int(PIX.shape[0]/9),int(PIX.shape[0]/9))

for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    axes[i].imshow(PIX[i,:,:,0], interpolation='none')
# Render the figure
plt.show()
```

Again, this is fairly simple. However, I get the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-a7bb604d1828> in <module>
      3 
      4 for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
----> 5     axes[i].imshow(PIX[i,:,:,0], interpolation='none')
      6 # Render the figure
      7 plt.show()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'imshow'
```

I tried the fixes on ['numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'imshow'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957776/numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-imshow/43957853) and ['numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'show' using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497992/numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-show-using-matplotlib), who seemed to have similar problems. However, none of the fixes seem to work in my case.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I tried to do that too, but it returns TypeError: 'Figure' object is not subscriptable, so I don't think that fig is enumerable. And just doing fig.imshow returns AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'imshow'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`axes` is a 2D ndarray so you have to use *two* indices.

Alternatively, you could replace

```
for i, ax in enumerate(axes)
```

With

```
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.ravel())
```